# How can i export data from a big single non-partitioned table to Google Cloud Storage as Date Partitioned files?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I want to export data from bigquery non-partitioned table (2 TB) to Google Cloud Storage as date partitioned files. 
So i can easily convert the big non-partitioned table to partition table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the schema of the table look like - what column will you use to determine the partitioning (ie. a date column?)? Is it necessary that you have the data in GCS or are you just trying to create a partitioned table from that original table?

I suggest you try the following: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#example

1) Create a new partitioned table.

> bq mk --time_partitioning_type=DAY mydataset.partitionedtable

2) Query the original table by the column you want to partition and set the new table's desired partition as the destination. Do this as many times as the number of partitions you want.

> bq query --allow_large_results --replace --noflatten_results \
>   --destination_table 'mydataset.partitionedtable$20160101' \ 'SELECT stn,temp from [mydataset.oldtable] WHERE mo="01" AND da="01" limit
>   100'

Comment: I want to create a partitioned table from the non-partitioned table, but if i try this solution, then i need to query each and every day. Currently our one query costs a lot of money. So if i want to do partition for last 6 months, then i want to this 180 times, which costs money. Thanks for your answer !