# How to move Partitioned Big Query Tables to GCS bucket as multiple files having the partitioned date in file name? Instead of having default numbers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to move the Bigquery table data in to GCS as multiple files(avro/parquet) having the partition date in file name ( not creating files having date as current datetime() in the file name).

I have tried the below query and I could see that it inserts only current date() or current datetime(). Also this extracts as one single file. I need to have multiple files based on the partitiondate.

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
uri='gs://test/'||Currentdate()||'/_*.avro',
format='avro',
overwrite=true) AS    
SELECT * from test_table
```

Instead of current_date how can I add _PARTITIONDATE in file name ?

I have seen a similar question being asked few years back .
[How can i export data from a big single non-partitioned table to Google Cloud Storage as Date Partitioned files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45012612/18361426)

But the solution was like this :

> Query the original table by the column you want to partition and set
> the new table's desired partition as the destination. Do this as many
> times as the number of partitions you want.
>
> bq query --allow_large_results --replace --noflatten_results 
> --destination_table 'mydataset.partitionedtable$20160101' \ 'SELECT stn,temp from [mydataset.oldtable] WHERE mo="01" AND da="01" limit
> 100'

Just like that I have 100 days partition and querying 100 times is not an optimal solution in this case.

Comment: You can't do that. Or you can imagine a complex script with execute immediate. First list the partition of the table. Then iterate over the list of partitions. For each partition, create a dynamic query (string concatenation) that perform the export with the date in the filename, and the correct WHERE close in your extract query. Execute immediate that string

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution in this case :

- Add a `Python` script for example with `Python` `Bigquery` [client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python)
- Execute your query in the script
- Add a `Group by` with `Python` in your script on the partitioned date
- You will have for example a structure like this :

```
'2022-05-22' => [
     {
      key1: value1,
      key2: value2,
     },
     {
      key1: value1,
      key2: value2,
     }
     ...
]
```

- For each group, generate the filename based on the key `date` and partition
- [Export](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html) the group values to `GCS` file

Comment: let me try this way

Comment: @vidhya sagar , let me know how did you achieve your results?